# Android - tirar a tela de splash do back-stack

Tags: java, android

Estou terminando um trabalho de faculdade onde um aplicativo deve apresentar uma tela de splash e, após, uma tela de login. Eu gostaria que, assim que a tela de splash fosse terminada, ela saísse do histórico.

A estrutura é a seguinte: S (splash) -> L (Login) -> R (resto do sistema). O histórico fica da seguinte forma: S, L, R. Gostaria que ficasse apenas L, R, pois quando o usuário voltar na tela de login, o aplicativo deve fechar.

O código da tela de splash é esse:

```
package activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Window;
import br.bravosix.tarefas.R;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_splash);

        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1500);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent login = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(login);
    }
}
```

Usar a flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, sugerido como solução em outras perguntas, não resolveu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se isso resolve:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Intent login = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(login);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Resposta rápida e ainda resolveu meu problema! Obrigado! (ainda não posso aceitar a resposta, mas assim que puder aceito).